# "too many open files" error after deleting many files

Tags: c++, linux

My program creates a log file every 10 seconds in a specified directory. Then in a different thread, it iterates the files in that directory. If the file has content it compresses it and uploads it to external storage, if the file is empty, it deletes it. After the program runs for a while I get an error `"too many open files" (gzopen failed, errno = 24)`.

When I looked inside `/proc/<pid>/fd` I see many broken links to files in the same directory where the logs are created and the word `(deleted)` next to the link.

Any idea what am I doing wrong? I checked the return values in both threads, of the `close` function (in the thread which writes the logs), and in the `boost::filesystem::remove` (the thread which compresses and uploads the non empty log files and deletes empty log files). All the return values are zero while the list of the `(deleted)` links gets longer buy 1 every 10 seconds.

I think this problem never happened to me on 32 bits but recently I moved to 64 bits and now I got this surprise.

Comment: Do you ever close the files?

Comment: Not only I close them I also check the return value of the close function, all return values are zero

Comment: Where is your [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mvce)? C'mon, you're a long-time SO user!

Comment: We won't know how to help you unless you post more code.

Comment: Check your ulimit -n settings? It is possible that your new machine (the 64 bit OS) has different ulimit defaults than the old one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are neglecting to close files you open.

From your description, it sounds like you `close` the files you open for logging in your logging thread, but you go on to say that you just `boost::filesystem::remove` files after compressing and/or uploading.

Remember that:

- Any compressed file you opened with `gzopen` has to be `gzclose`d
- Any uncompressed file you open to compress it has to be closed.
- If you open a file to check if it's empty, you have to close it.
- If you open a file to transfer it, you have to close it.

---

Output of `/proc/pid/fd` would be very helpful in narrowing this down, but unfortunately you don't post it. Examples of how seemingly unhelpful output gives subtle hints:

```
# You forgot to gzclose the output file after compressing it
l-wx------ user group 64 Apr 9 10:17 43 -> /tmp/file.gz (deleted)

# You forgot to close the input file after compressing it
lr-x------ user group 64 Apr 9 10:17 43 -> /tmp/file (deleted)

# You forgot to close the input file after logging
l-wx------ user group 64 Apr 9 10:17 43 -> /tmp/file (deleted)

# You forgot to close the input file after transferring it
lr-x------ user group 64 Apr 9 10:17 43 -> /tmp/file.gz (deleted)
```

Comment: You are right! and you are a genius :) When the I check the file size I opened it to pass fd to `fstat` but never closed it. It is clear you understand software development, thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it helped. Remember that you can simply `stat` a file instead of `open`+`fstat`+`close`

Comment: Once again, thanks a lot for your wise comments, I'll sure look into it once I'll handle all the other burning issues :)