# Java nio2 Directory is not closed. Causes "too many open files" error

Tags: java, linux, file, tomcat, centos

I am creating a lot of temp directories for batch processing using this:

```
Path tmp = Files.createTempDirectory("tmp-images");
```

The directory may contain 1-50 image files. I am deleting the directory after processing using Apache `FileUtils`:

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(tmp.toFile());
```

The directory is deleted but I am running into "too many open files". `lsof` is giving me this:

```
java    DIR  253,0   6  136899239 /opt/tomcat/temp/tmp-images1570439806870910607 (deleted)
java    DIR  253,0   6  136899237 /opt/tomcat/temp/tmp-images2456811184361231168 (deleted)
java    DIR  253,0   6  136899237 /opt/tomcat/temp/tmp-images2456811184361231168 (deleted)
java    DIR  253,0   6  136899238 /opt/tomcat/temp/tmp-images8109733179118089091 (deleted)
java    DIR  253,0   6   69527104 /opt/tomcat/temp/tmp-images8763413559313243911 (deleted)
java    DIR  253,0   6  136927313 /opt/tomcat/temp/tmp-images8168355305097994981 (deleted)
```

How to delete nio2 temp directory without open file handle?

Comment: I believe this means you're leaking open file handles. The files are still open so they cannot be deleted completely.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544411/too-many-open-files-error-after-deleting-many-files

Comment: All files were closed. It was the directory.

Comment: Can you post the full code opening and closing the files?

Comment: @Tunaki Please read my answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've found the bug. I've used this:

```
List<Path> result = Files.list(tmp).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This leaves the directory OPEN two times!

The right way is actually this:

```
List<Path> result;
try(Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(tmp)){
    result = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

java doc:

> The returned stream encapsulates a DirectoryStream. If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are completed.

Comment: I just got hit by same issue. It is plain bad API design, it should never return `Stream<>` if `try-with-resources` is required.